# Improve UX of suggesting edits when edits are pending

Tags: feature-request, suggested-edits, user-experience

I saw a post that I wanted to improve on a site where I did not have 2K rep yet. I wanted to fix the grammar to improve the post, but was met with a very bland error message:

[image]

No CSS, no proper SE layout, just a plain line saying to try again later. I refreshed, same thing.

I would like to suggest this small message appear just as a bubble on the Edit link when it's clicked, not as an entirely separate web page.

Comment: Good idea. But remember that it only happens if you went to some question *and then* someone suggested the edit. Otherwise "edit" would be greyed out.

Comment: That would screw with my morning routine then :P I check all the hot questions that look interesting, and they open up in new tabs. I go through them one at a time